# insert multiple value from php into matching name/id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm still confuse on this problem, my knowledge is still not that good regarding this matter since im still a student and willing to learn. the problem is by using php inputs. How can i insert this multiple inputs using at least 1 query together their corresponding name/id.

assuming each of this names have existing id's
*note that the names where from search results, it maybe random names
Here's a visual aid:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to know how you can remove the duplicates? Or do you want to add values everytime you submit? Or do you want a query that will sum up all the quizp for a specific user? I'm not quite sure what your question is

Comment: inputs will go to a specific user

Comment: Yeah that's obvious, but I still do not get what you're asking for

Answer (score 0):

You can do a multi insert if you're inserting these rows for the first time. :

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (id_student, quizp) 
VALUES (1234567, 30), (1234567, 40), (1234567, 70);
```

See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html).

Comment: inputs are random, it may be more than 20+ inputs

Comment: @Ron That's fine. Just dynamically create the SQL.

Comment: the names where generated by search, and its randoms names may appear